# ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission gives Crash on Android 10 Huawei 5T Nova

Tags: android, android-10.0

dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTraceVMStack.java, line -2
android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1194) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:904) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:652) at com.android.server.wm.HwActivityStarter.startActivity(HwActivityStarter.java:292) at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1647)

Intent uses the below classname for auto start application for Huawei

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.component = ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity")
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```